# Why does this batch variable never change even when set?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
SET first=0
FOR %%N IN (hello bye) DO (
SET first=1
echo %first%
echo %%N
)
```

It seems that the variable "first" is always 0.  Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Batch Variables Won't Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9681863/windows-batch-variables-wont-set)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

With batch files, variables are expanded when their command is read - so that would be as soon as the `for` executes. At that point, it no longer says `echo %first%`, it literally says `echo 0`, because that was the value at the point of expansion.

To get around that, you need to use delayed expansion by surrounding your variable name with `!` instead of `%` - so that would be `echo !first!`. This may require you to start cmd.exe with the /V parameter, or use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` in the beginning of your batch file (just after `echo off`).

If you type `set /?`, you'll see a much more detailed explanation of this at the end of the output.