# Variable in replacement s/// in loop does not change? Why?

Tags: perl

This is driving me nuts.  Help?

It looks to me like inside a Perl `foreach` loop, variables outside of a replacement pattern change as expected, but a variable inside a replacement pattern gets "stuck".  It's almost as though when perl encounters a `s///` replacement pattern inside a `foreach` code block, it interpolates the replacement pattern contents the first time through the loop and never again.

Here is some test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@replacements=("a", "b", "c");
@input=("xxletterxx");

foreach $replacement (@replacements) {
        foreach $line (@input) {
                $line=~s/xxletterxx/$replacement/g;
                print "R: $replacement\n";
                print "L: $line\n";
        }
}
```

I think it should print this:

```
R: a   
L: a   
R: b   
L: b   
R: c   
L: c
```

...but instead it prints this:

```
R: a  
L: a  
R: b  
L: a  <--- Why isn't this 'b'?  
R: c  
L: a  <--- Why isn't this 'c'?
```

Notice how the "L" value is still "a" inside the replacement pattern even though elsewhere in the code block it's changing with the members of `@replacements`?

Why is that?

I feel like Perl is suddenly broken, or I've lost my mind.

It almost seems like [this DOS behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949978/why-does-this-batch-variable-never-change-even-when-set) is occurring in perl.

Answer (score 6):

This loop control:

```
foreach $line (@input)
```

aliases `$line` to each element of `@input` so the first time you do the substitution, you've changed not only `$line` but `$input[0]` as well. After that, the `xxletterxx` is gone, so no more substitutions are happening because the `/xxletterxx/` is not matching.

To make it work the way you wanted, you need to break the aliasing, either by iterating over a clone of the `@input` array:

```
foreach $line (@{[@input]})
```

or by copying of `$line` to another variable before modifying it, treating `$line` as readonly in the body of the loop:

```
foreach $line (@input) {
        $modifiedline = $line;
        $modifiedline=~s/xxletterxx/$replacement/g;
        print "R: $replacement\n";
        print "L: $modifiedline\n";
}
```

Comment: `for (@input) { my $line = $_; ... }` is less wordy

Comment: Yes, probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `xxletterxx` to replace with `b` or `c` because you already replaced it with `a`.

Answer (score 0):

As hobbs, said, the problem is once you have replaced `xxletterxx` with `a`, the pattern no longer matches and thus the replacement doesn't occur. I'm not sure what your eventual goal is, but this works

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @replacements=("a", "b", "c");

foreach my $replacement (@replacements) {
  my $line = "xxletterxx";
  $line=~s/xxletterxx/$replacement/g;
  print "R: $replacement\n";
  print "L: $line\n";
}
```

as does this

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @replacements=("a", "b", "c");
my @lines = ("xxletterxx") x 3;

foreach my $replacement (@replacements) {
  my $line = shift @lines;
  $line=~s/xxletterxx/$replacement/g;
  print "R: $replacement\n";
  print "L: $line\n";
}
```

plus I've added `strict` and `warnings` for you :-)

Edit: a possibly more interesting example would be a modification of the last, which for each replacement attempts to change each element of `@lines` in turn, and stops once a replacement succeeds.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @replacements=("a", "b", "c");
my @lines = ("xxletterxx") x 3;

foreach my $replacement (@replacements) {
  foreach my $line (@lines) {
    last if $line=~s/xxletterxx/$replacement/g;
  }

  print "R: $replacement\n";
  print "A: @lines\n";
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  The eventual goal is to run through a list of value sets, spitting out a form for each set with the values replacing fields in a template.

Specifically, I have a small snippet of a Nagios config and a table of host attributes.  For each row in the table I want to spit out a host definition with those attributes filled in.  I have a template host definition with the fields identified by things like "xxhostgroup_namexx" and "xxhost_aliasxx".