# "Counter" in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a Batch file that will increment a variable by 1 each time it loops, and then check if the variable is equal to 5, and if it isn't, it loops again. I know there's probably a while loop for this, but I didn't know how to do that, and I'm just enjoying learning Batch for fun right now

Here's the code, it doesn't work the way it should, it just displays a 0: and then does nothing else. So how would I go about fixing it? I have a feeling I'm setting and incrementing the variable wrong, and maybe it's confused about the 2 if statements? (Does it have an else if....?) Anyways, thanks for the help

```
@echo off
set /p i=0:
goto A

:A
set /p i=i+1:
if i != 5 goto C
if i == 5 goto B

:C
echo Test :D

:B
pause>nul
```

Note: I don't know a lot of Batch and I'm not a pro, but I like to learn and I'm just doing this for future reference, and because I enjoy it. So, this code probably isn't good, but I want to know how I can accomplish this.

Comment: I suggest you to review this post: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3487

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a way to simulate the while loop you are trying to accomplish. Only one `goto` is needed:

```
@echo off
set /a x=0
:while
if %x% lss 5 (
  echo %x%
  pause>nul
  set /a x+=1
  goto :while
)
echo Test :D
```

Comment: But how can I make that goto a different line when it reaches a certain point? (ex, x == 5)

Comment: Just add them at the end of the file, the commands inside if `%x% lss 5(...)` only are executed while x is less than 5. I'll update the answer to match what I think you want.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks I think I get it now, I was just confused because I'm used to using an else or something.

Comment: When I do this, it still just outputs a 0 :(

Comment: Press Enter to continue (I thought you wanted to execute `pause>nul` for each iteration of the loop)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949978/why-does-this-batch-variable-never-change-even-when-set

Comment: 10 years on and still an incredibly helpful answer!

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with a simple `FOR` command :

```
for /l %%x in (0,1,100) do (
echo %%x
)
```

You can replace `100` by the number you want

Answer (score 4):

To set a numerical value to a variable, you may use the `/a` switch:

> The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
>   is a numerical expression that is evaluated.

(Type `SET /?` for all the help).

Second, check your `goto` flow - this never loops back to A.

Third, check the syntax of the `if` expression (`!=` doesn't exist in batch).

Comment: Ahhhh thanks, I should've done my research on the != :D So how would I do that sort of thing then, in Batch?

Comment: Check the documentation of `if` (`if /?`) - you either use `IF NOT %i%==5` or `if %i% NEQ 5` (Not EQual) or `if %i% LSS 5` (LeSS)

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
@echo off
set var1=0

:loop
    set /a var1=%var1%+1

echo %var1%

if %var1% EQU 5 (
    goto :end
) else (
    goto :loop
)

:end
    pause
```

Comment: If anyone has time, could they explain what the )'s do? Or is it just syntax telling when the else part ends?

Comment: @user2152304 yes, it's only sintax. Without "()" batch breaks.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set a=0
:Count
set /a a=a+1
echo %a%
goto Count
```

Comment: Please explain the code you propose as a solution. I'll be of way more value if you explain what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
:a
cls

color c
echo --------------
echo start:
echo --------------
set /p start=
cls

echo --------------
echo start: %start%
echo --------------

echo --------------
echo stop:
echo --------------
set /p stop=
cls

echo --------------
echo start: %start%
echo --------------

echo --------------
echo stop: %stop%
echo --------------
echo. 
echo. 

echo Start in:
timeout /t 2 /nobreak >nul

echo. 5
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

echo. 4
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

echo. 3
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

echo. 2
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul

echo. 1
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
cls

echo --------------
echo start: %start%
echo --------------

echo --------------
echo stop: %stop%
echo --------------

echo.
echo.
echo.

echo ============================================
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
    %SendKeys% ">----"
    %SendKeys% "{enter}"
    :while 
    echo %start%
        %SendKeys% "%start%"
    %SendKeys% "{enter}"
    set /a start=start+1
    timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
    if %start% leq %stop% goto :while
goto :end

:end
echo ============================================
%SendKeys% ">----"
%SendKeys% "{enter}"

:c
echo count again? Y/N
set /p return=
if %return% == Y goto :a
if %return% == N goto :b
goto :c

:b
@end

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: please add more description to your answer