# Loop Execution with Counter

Tags: batch-file

I am having a list of variable which is 100 (a notepad file, MediaList.txt), but I want to do the execution in a span of 25, so what will be most easy way to do the same with the below mentioned loop. Basically I want to execute the below mentioned loop with the counter.

```
for /f %%I in (E:\MediaList.txt) do nsrjb -w -N %%I
```

Comment: See ["Counter" in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450163/) or any other topic found by running a Stack Overflow search with [\[batch-file\] counter](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+counter) as search string.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET /a blocksize=23
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" 100lines.txt') DO (
 SET /a progress=%%a %% %blocksize%
 IF !progress!==1 IF %%a neq 1 (
  REM pause here
  timeout /t 10
 )
 ECHO(nsrjb -w -N %%b
)

GOTO :EOF
```

For test purposes, I set the block size to 23, and use my standard 100-lines-of-text file `100lines.txt`

How you want to pause the process is your own concern. I simply used a 10-second delay using `timeout` change to suit yourself.

The required nsrjb commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(nsrjb` to `nsrjb` to actually execute nsrjb.

It's simply a matter of numbering each line using `findstr` which prefixes each line with `number:`, then tokenising on first token=the number (`%%a`) and second token (`%%b`)=line-tail, using the colon as a delimiter.

From there, delyed-expansion is required to (calculate line-number mod block-size). If that result is `1`, then we've processed a block of lines, so wait *unless* the line number is `1`, which means we're about to process the very first line.

So - process a block (you choose the size), wait (you choose the time) for timeout or keypress; repeat until done.

The `findstr` command converts the line in the file from

```
u:\dir\file.txt
```

to, for instance

```
4:u:\dir\file.txt
```

The `for` command uses `tokens = 1*` and `delims = :`

Taking the `delims` first, what this means is "divide the line into tokens, using `:` as a separator"

So `4:u:\dir\file.txt` would be split into 3 tokens, `4` `u` and `\dir\file.txt`.

If the tokens clause selected 1,2 and3 (`tokens=1,2,3`) then the token values `4` `u` and `\dir\file.txt` respectively would be assigned to `%%a` (the *metavariable* nominated in the `for` instruction, `%%b` and `%%c` respectively (incrementing alphabetical sequence).

The special token "number" `*` means `all of the line after the highest-nominated token number"

For `"tokens=1*"` then, two tokens are nominated (`1` and `*`) so the first token value `4` is assigned to `%%a` and the remainder of the line past the token separator following the highest token number nominated (`1`) would be assigned to the next *metavariable* alphabetically (`%%b`) so `u:\dir\file.txt` is assigned to `%%b`

Comment: Lot of Thanks, but little confuse about the second token (%%b), will it be possible to explain with little more detail........?