# Windows cmd.exe/batch: increment counter by one in a single line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

OK, so I've seen:

- [How do I run two commands in one line in Windows CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd)

... which tells me that ampersand `&` is the separator for multiple commands running on a single line in a batch; and:

- ["Counter" in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450163/counter-in-batch)

> To set a numerical value to a variable, you may use the `/a` switch

Basically, I want to set up a counter variable, then increment it, then print it, then run some command in `cmd.exe` - so that each time I call the "previous line" command by using up key <kbd>↑</kbd>, I'd get a new counter value printed.

So this is my test:

```
C:\bin>set cnt=0

C:\bin>set /a cnt=%cnt%+1 & echo %cnt%
10

C:\bin>set /a cnt=%cnt%+1 & echo %cnt%
21

C:\bin>set /a cnt=%cnt%+1 & echo %cnt%
32
```

Of course, my final usage would be `set /a cnt=%cnt%+1 & echo %cnt% & my_command.bat`, but I dropped out `my_command.bat` from this discussion.

Anyways - what I thought would be increment by 1, turns out to be increment by 11 ?!

... Actually, I think I can tell what the problem is now: the `set` command also prints out the new value of the `cnt` variable! and then after it, the `echo %cnt%` prints the old value!

So, what would be the right syntax for a one liner, where `set` just sets but doesn't print; `echo` prints the updated value; and where I can append an arbitrary command (a batch file) at the end of the one-liner (besides the trivial "just use `set` and don't use `echo`"?)

Comment: `set /a` always prints the result, as long as it's executed directly on command line. You can redirect it to nirvana: `set /a cnt+=1 >nul`. To use the new value within the same line is [a bit more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).

Comment: `set /A cnt=%cnt%+1` works, but `echo %cnt%` in the same line fails as it lacks [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); anyway, better use `set /A cnt=cnt+1` or even `set /A cnt+=1`; for echoing, either use delayed expansion like `echo !cnt!`, or use `call echo %%cnt%%` (in batch file) or `call echo %^cnt%` (in command prompt)...